# "Volume group not found" warning before asking for passphrase

Tags: disk-encryption, lvm, devuan

I get the following warnings at boot:

```
Volume group "xxxxx" not found
Cannot process volume group xxxxx
(several times)
```

Then it ask for my passphrase, and start correctly. It seems that the system try to find the LVM volume before opening the encrypted partition.

How can I remove those warnings?

Comment: So you encrypted the physical volumes, correct? What you’re seeing is probably a mechanism meant for folks who encrypt the logical volume instead. It’s harmless.

Comment: It is, but it is also annoying